# Is there a way to disable the css hover through javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, css, events

I have a parent element and its child element.

Currently the child is hidden and appears when you hover over the parent and disappears when you're no longer hovering over the parent, using css.

I need it so that the child element doesn't disappear when you move outside the parent element IF the mouse button is held down.
So I need to disable the hover if the mouse button is held down and then re-enable it on mouseup.

This is for a draggable element that needs its child element, the handle, visible when mousedown.

I need to do it without jquery and other libraries.

Comment: html/css would explain the problem you're having more so than words can.

Comment: Well I just wanted to know if there's an obvious way to disable/enable hover programmatically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EDIT: woops... didn't see the "without jquery" part... my bad, left my jquery answer just in case and added a Without JQuery answer lower down

You can add a specific class that enables the hover css like this:

```
.parentElement.hoverCSS:hover {
    .childElement {
        display: none;
    }
}
```

And then using jQuery you do this:

```
$(".parentElement")
    .on("mousedown", function() {
        $(".parentElement").removeClass("hoverCSS");
    })
    .on("mouseup", function() {
        $(".parentElement").addClass("hoverCSS");
    })
```

This adds an event on `mousedown` which removes the class `hoverCSS` which will remove the css that hides the child. The second event on `mouseup` re-adds the class which will re-enable the hiding of the child element on hover of the parent

**WITHOUT JQUERY**

Another way to do this WITHOUT jQuery or any kind of javascript for that matter (kind of a hack but it will work) is to change your parent element to a button and use the `:active` CSS like this:

```
.parentElement.hoverCSS:hover {
    .childElement {
        display: none;
    }
}

.parentElement.hoverCSS:hover:active {
    .childElement {
        display: block;
    }
}
```

Since the button is active when the mouse is being held down, this will display the child element